# TypeError: robots.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this error: TypeError: robots.map is not a function.
I reviewed the code several times can't find the bug.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
// import { robots } from './robots';

const CardList = ({ robots }) => { 
    return(
        
        <div>
            {
                robots.map((user, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Card 
                            key={i} 
                            id={robots[i].id} 
                            name={robots[i].name} 
                            email={robots[i].email} 
                            />
                    );
                })

                
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default CardList;
```

```js
App.js 

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';
import { robots } from './robots';




class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = { 
            robots:'robots',
                searchfield: ''}
    }
    render(){
        return(
                <div className='tc'>
                    <h1 className=''>RoboFriends</h1>
                    <SearchBox />
                    <CardList robots={this.state.robots}/>
                </div>
        );

    }

}

export default App;
```

---

I updated the initial code with App.js that calls CardList.

I recently started learning react and I hope to develop an app that lets you search for a user which instantly filters and render the name typed in the search box.

Comment: You'll have to show how you call `CardList` and what `robots` contains (`console.log(robots)` before the `return` line.)

Comment: robots is not an array

Comment: JJJ robots contain an array with objects in it. I console.log(typeof(robots)) and it returns a string instead of an array just like AyushGupta stated. Let me update the code I already posted with App.js that calls CardList.

Comment: Try using `JSON.parse(robots);` before map...

Comment: Thank you guys I found the bug. The value of robots in App isn't supposed to be in quotes and which explains the return string I get when I console.log(typeof(robots)) prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `robots` as `props` from `App internal state` and not from the imported file.

Set the state of `App` component from the imported `robots` file

```
import { robots } from './robots'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { 
      robots,
      searchfield: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className=''>RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox />
        <CardList robots={this.state.robots}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also using index as React key is a bad practice, You have a unique id in every robot object so use it as key, also read about the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and how to access the iterated elements

```
const CardList = ({ robots }) => (
  <div>
    {robots.map(robot => (
      <Card 
        key={robot.id} 
        id={robot.id} 
        name={robot.name} 
        email={robot.email} 
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: My reputation is less than 15 and stack won't show my vote. It worked. I saw the bug. The value for robots in App is not supposed to be in quotes which I erroneously did and which explains why I had the return value of string when I console.log(typeof(robots)). Thank you @Asaf Aviv.

Answer (score -1):

You're passing a string to be mapped, instead pass the robots list of objects and see the result.
These kind of errors are the result of passing something other than a list to be mapped